# PHPExcel VLOOKUP not appearing

Tags: php, phpexcel, vlookup, worksheet

I'm trying to use PHPExcel to do a VLOOKUP and from another Sheet but simply getting no formula appearing in the cell. Using another formula, like SUM(), works fine.

So I've programmatically created a bunch of Sheets. Here's the dummy Sheet I'm testing:

```
$newsheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$lytabname = ($year-1).' wk '.$thisweeknum.' Input data';
$newsheet->setTitle($lytabname);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($lytabname);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(A6,'00009');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(E6,'100');
```

If I go back to the first sheet:

```
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Then this works:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D6', '=SUM(\''.$lytabname.'\'!A6:A7)');
```

But this doesn't, Cell D6 on the first sheet is empty

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D6', '=VLOOKUP(A6,\''.$lytabname.'\'!A6:A7,5,FALSE)');
```

I want the formula in the cell because I want to paste data into what is the dummy sheet right now and have the VLOOKUP do its job in the resulting XLS. I'm using PHPExcel 1.8.0 and Excel5 i.e.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->setTempDir($server_path.'tmp');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd start by recommending that you upgrade to the version of PHPExcel from the latest develop branch on github, because there have been some fixes implemented in the VLOOKUP functionsince 1.8.0